# How to show list of all empty inputs on php check of form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am doing a PHP check of the form thats submitted and I would like to show users all fields they forgot to fill. I am using jQuery too, but users can just disable that, and you really need an server side checks of forms too.

The thing is, if there are 6 required fields and they submit form with 2 of them empty, the code shows only the first one, and after they submit again, it would show them the second one. What would you suggest to do that stuff?

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $message = "";

        if (trim($_POST['ign'])){
            if (trim($_POST['god'])){
                if (trim($_POST['replay_id'])){
                    if (trim($_POST['map_type'])){
                        if (trim($_POST['time_min']) AND trim($_POST['time_sec'])){
                            if (trim($_POST['description'])){
                                // Submit the form
                            }else{
                                $message .= "<li>Description is empty</li>";
                            }
                        }else{
                            $message .= "<li>Time not specified</li>";
                        }
                    }else{
                        $message .= "<li>Match type not specified.</li>";
                    }
                }else{
                    $message .= "<li>Replay ID not specified.</li>";
                }
            }else{
                $message .= "<li>God was not specified.</li>";
            }
        }else{
            $message .= "<li>In game name was not specified!</li>";
        }


        if (!empty($message)){
            $message = "<div style='text-align:left; display: inline-block;'><ul>".$message."</ul></div>";
        }else{
            $message = "Submit succesfull";
        }

        echo "<div id='close-message'><div class='admin-message'>$message</div></div>";
    }
```

The only other way of doing it I can think of if this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $message = "";
    $pass = TRUE;

    if (!trim($_POST['ign'])){          $message .= "<li>In game name was not specified!</li>"; $pass = FALSE;  }
    if (!trim($_POST['god'])){          $message .= "<li>God was not specified.</li>";          $pass = FALSE;  }
    if (!trim($_POST['replay_id'])){    $message .= "<li>Replay ID not specified.</li>";        $pass = FALSE;  }
    if (!trim($_POST['map_type'])){     $message .= "<li>Match type not specified.</li>";       $pass = FALSE;  }
    if (!trim($_POST['description'])){  $message .= "<li>Description is empty</li>";            $pass = FALSE;  }
    if (!trim($_POST['time_min']) AND trim($_POST['time_sec'])){    $message .= "<li>Time not specified</li>";  $pass = FALSE;  }

    if ($pass){
        $message = "Submit succesfull";
        // Submit the form
    }else{
        $message = "<div style='text-align:left; display: inline-block;'><ul>".$message."</ul></div>";
    }

    echo "<div id='close-message'><div class='admin-message'>$message</div></div>";
}
```

Is there other way to do it? Again, purely PHP, jQuery is there, but it can be disabled, also HTML5 does not work in all browsers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're after is to get rid of all the `if` statements and make your code a bit cleaner, this may be a possible solution:

Setup an array with the required fields and their corresponding "required" error messages. Loop through the array and match the fields against `$_POST` to spot any required fields that was not set, adding any such field's error message to the `$errors` array.

Any errors found will then be displayed as an unordered list. If there were no errors, a success message will be displayed.

```
// Set some values for the example
$_POST['submit'] = '1';
$_POST['ign'] = 'foo';
$_POST['god'] = 'bar';
$_POST['description'] = 'baz';

// Validate required fields if submitted 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $required = array(
        'ign'         => 'In game name was not specified!',
        'god'         => 'God was not specified',
        'replay_id'   => 'Replay ID not specified',
        'map_type'    => 'Match type not specified',
        'description' => 'Description is empty',
        'time_min'    => 'Time not specified',
        'time_sec'    => 'Time not specified',
    );
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($required as $field => $errorMessage) {
        if (isset($_POST[$field]) && trim($_POST[$field]) != '') {
            continue; // All is well, check next required field
        }

        // No value was set for this required field
        $errors[] = $errorMessage;
    }

    if ($errors) {
        // Show any errors (use array_unique() to avoid duplicate error messages
        // on time_min/time_sec fields)
        $message = ""
            . "<div style='text-align:left; display: inline-block;'>"
            .     "<ul>"
            .         "<li>"
            .             implode('</li><li>', array_unique($errors))
            .         "</li>"
            .     "</ul>"
            . "</div>";
    }
    else {
        // All is well
        $message = "Submit successful";
    }

    echo ""
        . "<div id='close-message'>"
        .     "<div class='admin-message'>$message</div>"
        . "</div>";
}
```

Output (indented for improved readability):

```
<div id='close-message'>
    <div class='admin-message'>
        <div style='text-align:left; display: inline-block;'>
            <ul>
                <li>Replay ID not specified</li>
                <li>Match type not specified</li>
                <li>Time not specified</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wait what? How does this code add the error messages to the errors list? Or the continue actually means, it will ignore rest of the code and start with new item in the array right away? Also, Isnt looping more resource demanding than using just those ifs in my second code? Thanyway, thanks for response, I did not think of arrays.

Comment: Yes, that is how `continue` works. As for your other question, I would say that the nanosecond performance difference between a loop and repeated if statements is a non-issue when dealing with this kind of code. Readability, maintainability and a clear structure is way more important.

Comment: Ah, I actually never had to use continue, so never bothered to find what exactly it does :D Also, thats true, so Ill probably use the arrays for that :) Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to put my error messages next to the fields that caused the error and run the whole thing based on an array to keep the code DRY:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $fields = array(
        'ign' => 'In game name was not specified!',
        'god' => 'God was not specified.',
        ...
    );
    $message = "";
    $error = array();
    $pass = TRUE;

    foreach ($fields as $fld => $errmsg) {
        if (!trim($_POST[$fld])) {
            $message .= "<li>$errmsg</li>"; 
            $error[$fld] = $errmsg; 
            $pass = FALSE; 
        }
    }
```

I left your `$message` variable in there because it might be nice for your users to get a message at the top of the form and next to any erroneous fields. Typically I would just say "Your form submission had errors - see below".

Then down in your form display code display the value of `$error[$fld]` appropriately.  (I'm assuming you are displaying the form again to let the users fix the fields that they didn't fill in the first time.)

So before your form might have looked like this (if you are using a table):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">In Game Name:</td>
    <td><input name='ign' type='text' /></td>
  </tr>
  ...
```

and now it will look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">In Game Name:</td>
    <td><input name='ign' type='text' /></td>
    <td><?= @$error['ign'] ?></td>
  </tr>
  ...
```

With a very little bit of work you could style your field label with a color to draw the user's attention and etc.

Of course if your form is straightforward then you could have another array (or extension of the $fields array above) which would do all this for you again in a simple loop:

```
$fields = array(
    'ign' => array('label' => 'In Game Name:', 'error' => 'In game name was not specified!'),
    'god' => array('label' => 'God Mode:', 'error' => 'God was not specified.'),
    ...
);
```

Comment: I am actually putting red border around all fields that are empty/contain error instead of placing another error message next to them, as the form and whole page has to be responsive, so I cant afford to have it too wide. But thats actually pretty nice answer.